# How to exclude jar file in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

```
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.lang3.AnnotationUtils found in modules commons-lang3-3.4.jar (:XXXXX:) and commons-lang3-3.9.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9)
```

I am using the `org.apache.commons: commons-lang3: 3.9` implementation in my project. But the `jar` file I want to include has `org.apache.commons: commons-lang3: 3.4` version. This causes duplicated class error. How can I handle this?

I used this;

```
implementation(name: 'xxxxxxx', ext: 'aar') {
        exclude(group = "org.apache.commons", module = "commons-lang3")
    }
```

but he gave this error;
`Cannot set the value of read-only property 'module' for configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-media-compat'
}
```

Try this way.